# Makefile for a small JNI project

Tags: makefile, gcc, jni

So I'm going to publish this small project on GitHub and I thought I'd better do a makefile for it. The source code consists of

- 1 Java Class
- 1 Native JNI module written in C
- 1 stdlib wrapper object written in C (for LD_PRELOAD)

The purpose of the Makefile is to compile the two shared objects from the C-Source.

Here it is

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-nostartfiles -fpic -shared -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -Werror
OUT=bld
OUTFILES = $(OUT)/bind.so $(OUT)/bindsetter.so
JNI_AUTO_HEADER=$(OUT)/com_daftdroid_droidlib_bind_ClientBind.h

#Two locations needed to get all the JNI header files
JNI_INCLUDE=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include \
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux

#Add the includes to the compiler flags
CFLAGS+=$(foreach d, $(JNI_INCLUDE), -I$d)

all: $(OUTFILES)

$(OUTFILES): $(OUT)/%.so: %.c $(JNI_AUTO_HEADER)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(JNI_AUTO_HEADER): ClientBind.java
    javac ClientBind.java -d $(OUT) -h $(OUT)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm bld/* -rf
```

So some questions: `CC=gcc` is this a bit presumptuous? `CFLAGS` - well these all assume GCC too. What about inflicting `-Werror` on people - on *my* computer there are no warnings as it stands.

I hate this: `JNI_INCLUDE=/usr....` that is seriously installation dependent. What's a better way of doing this?

I have this header file `JNI_AUTO_HEADER` that javac can generate from the .java source, so therefore I consider it a build artifact which the makefile is responsible for. Do you agree? Also I've made *all* of the .so files dependent on `JNI_AUTO_HEADER` but hey, there's only two of them so I guess it's not worth worrying about.

Also I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing this in my source file:

```
// This include generated in the build directory at compile time
#include "bld/com_daftdroid_droidlib_bind_ClientBind.h"
```

(without getting into a much more complex build process)

Any other comments welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `CFLAGS` conventionally control the compilation. Linking options, that is

  ```
  -nostartfiles -shared -ldl
  ```

  are better be separated into `LDFLAGS`.
- `-Werror` is always a good idea. You don't want your users to run potentially incorrect code, do you?
- I recommend to make `$(OUT)` directory automatically.

  ```
  $(OUTFILES): | $(OUT)
  $(OUT):
      mkdir $(OUT)
  ```

  See [order-only dependencies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) for details.
- `JNI_AUTO_HEADER` *is* a build artifact, and yes `make` is responsible for it. I see no reason for confusion.
- As for `#include "bld/com_daftdroid_droidlib_bind_ClientBind.h"`, consider adding

  ```
  -include $(JNI_AUTO_HEADER)
  ```

  to `CFLAGS`, or passing it via -D option (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362675/macro-substitution-in-include-directive) for details)
- I don't know the correct way to figure out Java include paths; maybe `java.home` is a good place to start? You'd need a small Java app to print it though.

Comment: `LDFLAGS` turned out to be crucial I needed to do `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)` so the `-ldl` was specified after the output file or it wouldn't link at all. (error introduced while refactoring for this post). I'm normally used to `CFLAGS` for all the compilation units and `LDFLAGS` "at the end" and I hadn't considered that in this case, each unit is linked individually.

Comment: `-include $(JNI_AUTO_HEADER)` was a good find. Note you can get away without including this header at all, unless you add `-Wmissing-prototypes`. Thanks for taking the time to review my Makefile!

Answer (score 0):

I've got some better logic for the JNI include paths.

- Test to see if the user has already set JNI_INCLUDE
- If not, make a best guess based on JAVA_HOME

The logic is now

```
ifndef JNI_INCLUDE

#If the user hasn't supplied JNI_INCLUDE path
#then use a default based on JAVA_HOME

ifndef JAVA_HOME
$(error JAVA_HOME not set)
endif

JNI_INCLUDE=$(JAVA_HOME)/include \
    $(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
endif
```